# Symbol For Reversing An Ordered Set?

Tags: notation, order-theory

Is there a symbol for a reversed ordered set?  E.g. the symbol which would mean the ordered set:

```
(1, 2, 8, 4, 9, 6)
```

Becomes:

```
(6, 9, 4, 8, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Sometimes you see $X^{op}$ playing this role, sometimes $X^*$. The first one is in accordance with the category-theoretic notation, the second one is probably here to reflect the fact that it's a dual operation. There are probably other notations but those are the ones I know

Comment: Some authors use $X^{\partial}$, where the 'd' like symbol must be a mnemonic to order-dual.